# Transpose keeping all combinations of multiple values for id variable in SAS

Tags: sas, transpose

I want to transpose a table from long to wide but I have more than one value for each Key. I want the transposed table to have one line for each combination of Id and Key, so for this example item, I'd have 8 lines after transposition. The Id variable would be preserved, each distinct Key would be all combinations of different values for the same key. So 2 * 2 * 1 * 1 * 1 * 2 = 8 lines.

```
data grades;
input Id Key $ Value $;
cards;
219381 Category Something
219381 Category Another
219381 Color    White
219381 Color    Black
219381 Sport    Football
219381 Gender   Male
219381 Size     Big
219381 Quality  Good
219381 Quality  Bad
;
run;
```

This is what I want to come out after this complex transposition:

```
Id      Category  Color Sport    Gender Size Quality
219381  Something White Football Male   Big  Good
219381  Something White Football Male   Big  Bad
219381  Something Black Football Male   Big  Good
219381  Something Black Football Male   Big  Bad
219381  Another   White Football Male   Big  Good
219381  Another   White Football Male   Big  Bad
219381  Another   Black Football Male   Big  Good
219381  Another   Black Football Male   Big  Bad
```

Any ideas how I can achieve this?
I've tried many things without success.

Comment: I think the SASsy way to solve this is a HOH (Hash of Hashes); I don't have time to write one at the moment as it's something I don't do often enough to remember off the top of my head.  http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/255-2011.pdf would be a good start, though, and i'll come back and write it if I have some time.

Comment: @Joe, if you could post your SASsy solution with HoHs I think that would be very instructive (not only for me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this looks like you want a cartesian product for different keys that are stored in one table. While not very SAS-like, one way you can get the result you're looking for is by using `PROC SQL` with joins on the same table, simulating individual tables for these different key types.

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE grades_combos AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        g.id, category.value as category, color.value as color, sport.value as sport,
        gender.value as gender, size.value as size, quality.value as quality
    FROM grades g
    INNER JOIN grades category ON category.id = g.id AND category.key = 'Category'
    INNER JOIN grades color ON color.id = g.id AND color.key = 'Color'
    INNER JOIN grades sport ON sport.id = g.id AND sport.key = 'Sport'
    INNER JOIN grades gender ON gender.id = g.id AND gender.key = 'Gender'
    INNER JOIN grades size ON size.id = g.id AND size.key = 'Size'
    INNER JOIN grades quality ON quality.id = g.id AND quality.key = 'Quality'

    ORDER BY id, category, color, sport, gender, size, quality
    ;
QUIT;
```

You could probably make this more flexible and generic, perhaps wrapping this in a macro that generates the `JOIN` statements based on an arbitrary set of keys.

Comment: Agree with the non-sassiness, but it's definitely a good solution (although, very slow with even medium size data).

Comment: That worked, I just had to change the inner join for a left join on my real problem because not all keys exist in every id.

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, I can think of the following two approaches:

1. Use a by-statement? (requires sorted data)
2. Create a third variable which is the concatenation of the other 2
   variables and use that one.